# Change database connection depending on route in express.js with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Is it possible to change the database connection in `sequelize` depending on the route?

For example, Users have access to 2 different installations in a website:
 - `example.com/foo`
 - `example.com/bar`

Upon login users are redirected to `example.com/foo` 
To get all their tasks for the `foo` site, they need to visit `example.com/foo/tasks`

The `bar` site uses a separate database and thus if they want to get all their tasks for `bar` they have to go to `example.com/bar/tasks`

Every installation has its own database, and all databases have the same schema.

Is it possible to change the database connection depending on which route is visited?

*login only occurs once

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible.  There are a number of ways to do this.  Here's how I might approach it.

#### Router.js

```
var router = express.Router()
// This assumes the database is always the 2nd param, 
// otherwise you have to enumerate
router.use('/:database/*', function(req, res, next){
  req.db = req.params.database;
  next();
}
```

#### Connection.js

```
var fooDB = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/foo');
var barDB = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/bar');
module.exports = {
  foo: fooDB,
  bar: barDB,
}
```

#### Tasks.js

```
 var connection = require('connection);
 function getTasks(req, params){
   var database = connection[req.db]; 
   //database now contains the db you wish to access based on the route.
 }
```

That said, there are some interesting problems you'll have to face when you want to duplicate the schema across both, but that's probably best for another question.

I hope this helps!

Comment: how to do this dynamic way? for example you are hard coding the two databases in connection.js? if there are 1000 database coming dynamically how you handle?

Comment: consider blogging system for *.blog.dev and subdomain is database name, how many connection did you need ?

Comment: I have the same trouble

Answer (score -1):

I think is better to change collections depending on the route.
Have `foo_tasks` collection and `bar_tasks` collection in the same database.

Or have the attribute `type` in the `tasks` collection that specifies if the task is a "foo task" or a "bar task".